# How to do a simple http get ajax style using mootools 1.2.1

Tags: ajax, mootools

I'm trying to do a simple ajax GET that returns the html from google.com but with the following I keep hitting my onFailure. And when I hit status i get a 0, yet when I attempt to output the responseText I get nothing.

Anyone done a simple request like this in mootools 1.2.1?

```
function addSomeAction() {
                        el.onclick = function() {
                        var uri = "http://www.google.com";

                                            var myRequest = new Request({
                                                url: uri,
                                                method: 'get',
                                                onRequest: function(){
                                                    alert("loading...");
                                                },
                                                onSuccess: function(responseText){
                                                    alert("hi");
                                                },
                                                onFailure: function(responseFail){
                                                    alert("fail: " + responseFail.responseText);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            myRequest.send();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the framework used, you cannot do cross-domain AJAX requests. This is to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks and is a limitation imposed by the web browser.

Therefore, you can only fetch the HTML source of a page which on the same domain as the originating request.

There are specifications allowing for the asynchronous transfer of JSON data residing on another domain (JSONP), but they will not help you in this case.

Comment: he can use 1. a local proxy that uses curl to fetch a remote url. 2. YQL via JSONP, though it may not be the most performant service to rely upon. 3. there's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - www.enable-cors.org, though it wont work with google :)